# insertValidationMessage knockout not working

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-validation

i am using knockout validation i want to show custom message by my own function
here is my code for ko validations

```
  ko.validation.init({

   // registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: false,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null,
    grouping: { deep: true, observable: true },
    registerExtenders: true,
    insertValidationMessage: function (element) {

        var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
        span.className = "validationMessage";

        if ($(element).hasClass("error-before"))
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, element);
        else
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, element.nextSibling);

        return span;
    }
});
```

but insertvalidationmessage is not being called Am i doing any thing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init` method only supports overriding configuration properties, so if you want to override methods you need to do it directly on the `ko.validation` object.

So your initialization code should look like this:

```
ko.validation.init({
   // registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: false,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null,
    grouping: { deep: true, observable: true },
    registerExtenders: true
});

ko.validation.insertValidationMessage = function (element) {

    var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
    span.className = "validationMessage";

    if ($(element).hasClass("error-before"))
       element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, element);
    else
       element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, element.nextSibling);

    return span;
};
```